# JavaScript: How do I capture particular value in a string?

Tags: javascript

I have the below strings and I need to capture the number 31 digit from the Mem: line. Spaces are dynamic so I am unable to capture the right number.

String:

```
Swap:            1          0          1        
Mem:            31         27          3          0          1         18
```

I am trying the below code and couldn't go further.

```
let lines = output.split('\n');
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  var newArray = lines[i];

  if (newArray.indexOf('Mem:') > -1) {
    let n = newArray.split(":");

  }
}
```

Comment: please edit the question and add some string limiter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regex `Mem:\s*(\d+)` to get the first number after `Mem:` and unknown number of whitespaces to a capturing group. Then use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get the capturing group which is at the index `1`.

```js
const str = `Swap:            1          0          1        
Mem:            31         27          3          0          1         18`

const [, number] = str.match(/Mem:\s*(\d+)/)

console.log(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided with the 'Mem' string (presumably from your `lines` array) , it is this simple:

```js
const str = "Mem:            31122       27          3          0          1         18";
const subStr = str.split(':')[1].trim();
const num = subStr.substr(0,subStr.indexOf(' '));

console.log(num);
```

If there are other constraints not ideified in the question I'll alter the answer as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Randy. What if 31 is dynamic? Like it could be 300, 3134. Can we adjust the code accodingly?

Comment: Edited the answer to accommodate your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the line and get the first digits.

```js
var lines = 'Swap:            1          0          1        \nMem:            31         27          3          0          1         18',
    firstNum = lines.split('\n').find(s => s.includes('Mem')).match(/\d+/);

console.log(firstNum[0]);
```

Comment: The input in the original question is one string, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var lines = 'Swap:            1          0          1        \nMem:            31         27          3          0          1         18',
    firstNum = lines.split('\n').find(s => s.includes('Mem')).match(/\d+/);

console.log(firstNum[0]);
```